# Regular expression to scan a pattern from unbalanced start and stop delims

Tags: ruby, regex

How to extract a pattern from a log line with unbalanced start and stop delims. The start pattern in this case is "params = {" and the stop pattern is "}"

Log line:

```
"...params={...}..."
```

Output:

```
"params={...}"
```

Comment: Reduce the input string to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
params=\{[^\}]*\}
```

It means:

```
params=\{        # 'params={' sequence of characters
[^\}]            # non '}' character
*                # as many as possible
\}               # the next '}' character
```

Hope it helps.